# Why does Perl say that it can't find my module?

Tags: perl

I wanted to play with `XML::Rabbit`, however I've got a problem even with the simplest code. I managed to strip this into one line.

In a simple file, I use

```
use Class::Load;
```

and then:

```
perl test_optlist.pl

Can't locate Data/OptList.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::OptList module) (@INC contains: [CUT]) at /home/szymon/perl5/lib/perl5/Class/Load.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/szymon/perl5/lib/perl5/Class/Load.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at test_optlist.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test_optlist.pl line 2.
```

so let's install it:

```
$ cpanm Data::OptList
Data::OptList is up to date. (0.107)
```

Perl version:

```
This is perl 5, version 17, subversion 8 (v5.17.8) built for x86_64-linux
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I imagine `cpanm` uses a different build of Perl than `perl test_optlist.pl` does.

Comment: I'm guessing from the fact that you are using a dev build of Perl (why?!) that you have multiple builds of Perl installed. How do you manage the binaries installed by Perl modules (e.g. `cpanm`)? Do you use `perlbrew`? That would save you headaches.

Comment: @ikegami - thanks, looks like cpanm installed it in /usr/share/perl5/ while I don't have it in path. I use perbrew, I just compiled the new perl just to play with it a little bit. I don't remember where I have cpanm from :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're surely using another `perl`'s `cpanm`. Do

```
perlbrew install-cpanm
```

to install a version of `cpanm` under `perlbrew`'s control, make sure this new `cpanm` is the one found first in the path (though I suspect it will be), then try again